# Invalid ESRT GUID error shortly after boot

Tags: boot, uefi

Using 18.04.4 with kernel version 5.3.0-40, I recently started seeing a System Program error shortly after boot. I found this in /var/log/syslog:

```
Mar  5 10:20:27 basilico systemd[1]: Starting Firmware update daemon...
Mar  5 10:20:27 basilico boltd[1648]: power: guard '2' for 'fwupd' active
Mar  5 10:20:27 basilico fwupd[2579]: 15:20:27:0603 FuPluginUefi         failed to add /sys/firmware/efi/esrt/entries/entry0: ESRT GUID '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' was not valid
```

I found the invalid GUID in the following file

```
$ sudo cat /sys/firmware/efi/esrt/entries/entry0/fw_class
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

This [link](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/rzhang/linux/+/release/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-firmware-efi-esrt) shows each file in this directory and what they mean, but I cannot determine where the GUID comes from or what would constitute a valid value. According to info at that link, the GUID should be found in the directory name, e.g. `entry00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

I haven't tried simply deleting the `entry0` directory because the file sizes are all 4096 bytes, but the file contents are much smaller than that, figuring I won't be able to easily reconstruct the directory's contents:

```
$ ls -l /sys/firmware/efi/esrt/entries/entry0
total 0
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Mar  5 10:20 capsule_flags
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Mar  5 10:20 fw_class
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Mar  5 10:20 fw_type
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Mar  5 10:20 fw_version
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Mar  5 10:20 last_attempt_status
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Mar  5 10:20 last_attempt_version
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Mar  5 10:20 lowest_supported_fw_version
```

```
$ sudo tail -n +1  /sys/firmware/efi/esrt/entries/entry0/* 
==> /sys/firmware/efi/esrt/entries/entry0/capsule_flags <==
0x50000

==> /sys/firmware/efi/esrt/entries/entry0/fw_class <==
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

==> /sys/firmware/efi/esrt/entries/entry0/fw_type <==
1

==> /sys/firmware/efi/esrt/entries/entry0/fw_version <==
1

==> /sys/firmware/efi/esrt/entries/entry0/last_attempt_status <==
0

==> /sys/firmware/efi/esrt/entries/entry0/last_attempt_version <==
1

==> /sys/firmware/efi/esrt/entries/entry0/lowest_supported_fw_version <==
1
```

Other than the disconcerting System Program Error popup shortly after boot and the messages in `/var/log/syslog`, there are no other manifestations of the issue or stability problems.

Appreciate any leads.

Comment: The problem is related to updating UEFI. Check with: systemctl status fwupd (you can stop the daemon or disable it in case of problems). For more information en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fwupd